# X64dbg not showing me strings

Tags: reverse-engineering, cracking, x64dbg

For time attempting to crack and application. I know the gist of it, but I have come across a problem. When I try to search for a string it comes out blank. For insight this application is in Chinese and comes with a dll file. So I had to use google to copy the “account expired” message when you enter an expired key.

When I search for the “ account expired(in Chinese characters)” message string there is nothing. I even searched for the “confirm” string that is in the dialog box to close the application after a wrong/expired key is inputted. What I personally think is going in is the “account expired” message box that pops up is actually just a picture and therefore the words on it are not strings. But that can’t be since there is an interactive button on the dialog box. I even put my locale system in simplified Chinese but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not always are the strings available as text within the debugger.

Two reasons that come to mind are:

1. The string might be deobfuscated/encrypted within the application, which prevents easy modification or understanding of the code.
   You can use a tool such as [Detect it easy](https://github.com/horsicq/Detect-It-Easy) to find out if it's packed or not.
2. Make sure that you are searching within the correct file/DLL.

---

As an alternative, here are two solutions on how to find the "account expired" message.

1. Set breakpoints on the corresponding API's. Such as, for example, if it's a MessageBox, then set a breakpoint on [`sendMessageW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessagew)
2. Use the call stack to trace the call:

   [image]

Also, Remember, that reverse engineering or modifying software can be *illegal*.